# Lubuntu and Belkin F5U103v usb to serial : can i make it work under WINE?

Tags: usb, lubuntu, wine

I have a BELKIN usb-to-serial adapter, model F5U103v.
The accompanied drivers (at that time) are only for Windows XP.

My question:

I have Windows XP software that communicates via Belkin usb-to-serial with an old plc (port RS232). i.e to download/upload firmware. So far I was doing my job with Windows XP.

Now, I use Lubuntu...

Since the Belkin drivers only exist for Windows XP and the software I have to communicate with the old plc is also for XP, can I use WINE to run all this stuff in Lubuntu?

Is there any other way to make it communicate?

note: the plc software is old, I it only runs on XP, no Linux version exists and will not ever exist.

Belkin usb-2-serial drivers only exist for Windows XP and Mac OSX, They  are old and are not supported any more because there are newer usb-2-serial models.

Comment: Did you know that a good usb-serial adapter costs around 5€? Can you post the output of `lsusb` with the adapter plugged?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO your easiest path ahead would be to install XP in a virtual machine on your Ubuntu computer.  I have had no problems with USB devices passing through to XP virtual machines using VirtualBox.